# How to convert C++ Struct with Union into C#?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm trying to convert this piece of code from C++ to C# or CLI but nothing works till now, may anyone help me please.

```
ref struct token_t
{
    TokenTypes_t TokenType;     // enum class
    string       TokenString;    
     typedef  union
    {
        Keyword_t  KeywordID;  // enum class
        char       CharVal;   
        Operator_t OprID;    // enum type
    }; 
};
```

Comment: Show us, what you tried and where it is failing ? May be with some code samples which use them, where it seems to fail.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using the fact that the data is aliased in your program, then you can initially simply have additional 3 fields.

```
struct token_t
{
    TokenTypes_t TokenType;     // enum class
    string       TokenString;    
    Keyword_t  KeywordID;  // enum class
    char       CharVal;   
    Operator_t OprID;    // enum type
}
```

The final translation depends on the original need for the union. Often what results is an abstract base class with (for this case) 3 derived types, each containing one of the members of the original union. If the `TokenType` field is used to mark the currently valid member of the union, then that field would likely be removed since the concrete type of each instance would trivially determine the same information.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  Perhaps you could improve the question by posting example code of how & why you're using the union in C++ and that might shed some light on how we'd do the same in C#?